# VMworkstaition NIC 2 no interface name

Tags: nic

I have install 15.10 Server Wily with 1 NIC and after installation added additional NIC. But I only see eno16777736.

Second NIC not displayed

```
root@maas:/etc/udev/rules.d# lshw -class network
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: eno16777736
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:da:b3:e1
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=172.16.1.31 latency=0 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:02:05.0
       logical name: eno33554984
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:da:b3:eb
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd580000-fd59ffff memory:fdfe0000-fdfeffff ioport:2040(size=64) memory:fd520000-fd52ffff
root@maas:/etc/udev/rules.d#
```

Comment: Have you added the appropriate portion to the interfaces config?